# What development framework is best for Adobe AIR AS3 Mobile development in Flash Pro CS6?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, mobile, frameworks, air

I am developing an AIR app targeting iPhone and Android devices and looking for a good framework that will help streamline development and performance, provide a good set of mobile optimised UI components and allow freedom to import and use Flash classes.

I've looked at Starling and Feathers which looks great for creating screens and UI components but there seems to be some limitations to this namely the inability to use the flash.display.MovieClip and flash.media.Video classes. The starling movieclip seems a little simplistic and I cannot add video to the stage.

What other frameworks are out there that would help me to structure my code and the app and also give me easy access to mobile ready UI components? I am developing on a macbook pro with Flash Pro CS6 targeting Air 3.2 for iOs

cheers

Comment: Why not use Flex, which was originally built by Adobe (now by Apache), highly documented in the LiveDocs, and the built in framework for Flash?

Answer (score 0):

You can add MovieClips to the classic stage while Starling renders underneath, this method is not advised though because when mixing the two, there are performance concerns on mobile. This is due to the software vector rendering engine running to display the MovieClips.

What people are doing these days is using Dynamic Texture Atlas or MovieClip Converter to convert the MovieClips to Starling movieclips. Check this one out:

https://github.com/zenrobin/FlashMovieClipConverter

As for video, please check out StageVideo, as it is the hardware accelerated version of Video and is available in AIR.

http://www.overdigital.com/2012/01/09/the-ultimate-guide-to-understanding-advanced-video-delivery-with-air-for-mobile/